# The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect. fabric.api.local

Tags: python, directory, filenames, fabric

```
from fabric.api import env, lcd, local

local("onmode -ky>"'"C:\Program Files\HCL OneDB\explore\autotuner\log\db.log"'"&& onclean -ky>"'"C:\Program Files\HCL OneDB\explore\autotuner\log\db.log"'"")
```

the above code gives the error :

```
 Fatal error: local() encountered an error (return code 1) while executing 'onmode -ky>"C:\Program Files\HCL OneDB\exploreutotuner\log\db.log"&&  onclean -ky>"C:\Program Files\HCL OneDB\exploreutotuner\log\db.log"'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use some other ways to start and stop the server like "sc start onedb_1" and wait for the server to be online. don't run any another command while is starting